# c# split images into smaller blocks

Tags: c#, split

Hey, what I want to do is user selected how many columns for the image, then the image will be split into the columns that the user entered.

Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can crop using [`Bitmap.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx) by specifying the [`Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx) that you want to copy.

Comment: Okay, lets say the image has been split into few blocks, then how am I going to get the block of the image?

Comment: @jooshen: Each call to the Clone method will return a Bitmap object. You just need to maintain a collection of Bitmaps, for example: `List<Bitmap>`

Comment: Erm, I need to get each split image file in order to compare with another image. How am I going to get the split image file in coding?

Comment: @joonshen: Paul answered your question. `Bitmap.Clone` returns an instance of `Bitmap` representing the cropped image.